# How to filter Scan on Accumulo using RegEx

Tags: regex, accumulo

I've used scans over data stored in Accumulo before, and have gotten the whole result set back (whatever `Range` I specified).  The problem is, I would like to filter those on the server-side from Accumulo before the client receives them.  I'm hoping someone has a simple code example of how this is done.

From my understanding, `Filter` provides some (all?) of this functionality, but how is this used in practice using the API?  I see an example using Filter on the shell client, from the Accumulo documentation here: http://accumulo.apache.org/user_manual_1.3-incubating/examples/filter.html

I couldn't find any code examples online of a *simple* way to filter a scan based on regular expressions over any of the data, although I'm thinking this should be something relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Filter`](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/Filter.html) class lays the framework for the functionality you want. To create a custom filter, you need to extend `Filter` and implement the `accept(Key k, Value v)` method. If you are only looking to filter based on regular expressions, you can avoid writing your own filter by using [`RegExFilter`](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/user/RegExFilter.html).

Using a `RegExFilter` is straightforward. Here is an example:

```
//first connect to Accumulo
ZooKeeperInstance inst = new ZooKeeperInstance(instanceName, zooServers);
Connector connect = inst.getConnector(user, password);

//initialize a scanner
Scanner scan = connect.createScanner(myTableName, myAuthorizations);

//to use a filter, which is an iterator, you must create an IteratorSetting
//specifying which iterator class you are using
IteratorSetting iter = new IteratorSetting(15, "myFilter", RegExFilter.class);
//next set the regular expressions to match. Here, I want all key/value pairs in
//which the column family begins with "J"
String rowRegex = null;
String colfRegex = "J.*";
String colqRegex = null;
String valueRegex = null;
boolean orFields = false;
RegExFilter.setRegexs(iter, rowRegex, colfRegex, colqRegex, valueRegex, orFields);
//now add the iterator to the scanner, and you're all set
scan.addScanIterator(iter);
```

The first two parameters of the `iteratorSetting` constructor (priority and name) are not relevant in this case. Once you've added the above code, iterating through the scanner will only return key/value pairs that match the regex parameters.

Comment: Thanks Liz.  I actually dug around a bit and found a test case that Accumulo (ASF) has in their subversion:  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/accumulo/branches/ACCUMULO-578/server/src/test/java/org/apache/accumulo/server/test/iterator/RegExTest.java  This seems to basically lay it all out, in addition to your response.  Thanks again.